# R Notebook and knitr with a latex table?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

Is it possible to have a latex table in r notebook?

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work.

````
 ---
 title: "R Notebook"
 output: html_notebook
 ---


 ```{r}
 library(knitr)
 library(kableExtra)
 dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
 kable(dt, "latex")

 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the packages `magick` and `kableExra` to save the LaTeX table as an image with `kableExtra::kable_as_image()`. The image of the LaTeX table can then be rendered in the HTML output. Look at the linked [documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) for 'kableExtra' under the heading "Use LaTeX table in HTML or Word".